# Source that indicates which Sefira corresponds to which persona

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, historical-figures

The Ten Sefiros can be [correlated](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94_(%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94)#%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%98_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA) to people in Tanach. For example, Avraham is Chesed, Yitzchok is Gevurah, Moshe is Netzach, etc.

I'm looking for an early source which lays out these correlations. All I can find is Wikipedia articles..I assume this is from the Arizal.

Answer (score 3):

According to the link you posted, only 7 of the sefirot are connected to the people from tanach. And it goes as follows:

אברהם - חסד, 
יצחק - גבורה,
יעקב - תפארת,
משה - נצח, 
אהרן - הוד,
יוסף - יסוד,
דוד - מלכות.

The sources for this, can be found in the Zohar Chadash¹

> **אַבְרָהָם**, דְּדַרְגֵּיהּ **חֶסֶד** ([source](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar_Chadash,_Yitro.91?vhe=Zohar_Chadash&with=all&lang=bi))

(Avraham, his level is Chesed)

> וְאִינוּן חוּלָקֵיהוֹן דְּצַדִּיקַיָא בְּרָזָא דָּא, הַגְּדֻלָּה: דָּא
>   אַבְרָהָם. **הַגְּבוּרָה: יִצְחָק. הַתִּפְאֶרֶת: יַעֲקֹב. הַנֵּצַח:
>   חוּלָקָא דְּמשֶׁה. הַהוֹד: חוּלָקָא דְאַהֲרֹן** ([source](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar_Chadash,_Ki_Tisa.32?vhe=Zohar_Chadash&with=all&lang=bi))

(They are divided between the tzadikim here, Hagdula - Avraham, **Gvura - Yitzchak, Tiferet - Yaakov, Netzach - Moshe's part, Hod - Aharon's part**)

> צַדִיק **יְסוֹד** עָלְמִין, דַּרְגָּא **דְּיוֹסֵף** הַצַּדִיק ([source](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.235b.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_Zohar&with=all&lang=bi.))

(yesod olmin is the level of Yosef Hatzadik.)

> **הַמַּמְלָכָה**: חוּלָקָא **דְּדָוִד**. ([Source](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar_Chadash,_Ki_Tisa.32?vhe=Zohar_Chadash&with=all&lang=bi))

(Hamamlacha - or malchus, - is Dovid's part)

---

The same can be found in many other parts of the Zohar.

<sub>1. Composed in Middle-Age Spain (c.1100 - c.1400 CE). Zohar Chadash is a collection of manuscripts that were found containing material pertaining to the Zohar but not included in printed editions of the work. The manuscripts were later organized, mostly by Torah portion, and printed as their own work. [(Source)](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar_Chadash?lang=bi)</sub>

Comment: The English text is my own, so feel free to give tips.